# I couldn't find kendo grid refresh button functionality for the Angular version

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The Kendo Grid for jQuery has a refresh button in the pager (eg. [grid](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index)).
I couldn't find such functionality for the Angular version.
Is it possible to add something like that for the Angular version?

Example:

```
<ng-template kendoPagerTemplate>
     <kendo-pager-refresh-button (onRefresh)="refreshGrid()"></kendo-pager-refresh-button>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  The widget does not have that functionality.  You can vote for the feature request [here](https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1360630-refresh-button-in-grid) (did you copy and paste the code from there?).  You can easily make your own button with the same functionality outside of the widget though.

Comment: thanks xinthose! I also voted for this issue,  Actually, I copy-pasted that code from GitHub.
in angular, they have CSS classes like "k-button" and "k-pager-refresh" but no use of that. hope they will fix this issue soon.